# Static front page displaying twice

Tags: themes, homepage, customization

I am using a free SM theme (estate agent) on my WordPress site.

The theme allows for setting a static front page, which I did (the page is called 'events', and when I set it as home page its permalink became simply `www.example.com`).

The problem is the page is now displayed twice.

Here is [my website](http://padovafriendly.it).

Comment: We need to see the according template file. Do you have a `front-page.php` file? If so, please include its content to your question ([edit it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/96922/edit)). If not, please post the content of `page.php`, and if you don't have that either, it's `index.php`.

Comment: Yep, please post the **relevant** code from the template file your Events page is using, especially the bit around `<div class="articles">`.

Comment: Please switch to a default core Theme, such as Twenty Twelve, and disable all Plugins. Verify whether or not the issue persists. If it does not, activate Plugins one-by-one until you determine if one causes the issue. If not, then the issue is your Theme. As your current Theme is from a shady site that distributes Themes with "sponsored" footer links, includes "kill" code to prevent modification of those spammy footer links, and is distributed under a non-GPL-compatible license, you need to choose a better Theme to use.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize

Click on "Theme Options"

Now you can see your page sections that the second one is your first page that is repeated.

Click on pencil icon at the top left of the unwanted section.
Then on the list at the left you can see the name of your page, even you can change the source of your section with another one but if you do not want this section choose nothing from the list

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This answer is exactly what I needed. If I decide to add back another section I know to delete what is in section one first.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon this answer, I had "content" in the place holders for "**FRONT PAGE SECTION 1 PLACEHOLDER**" and "**FRONT PAGE SECTION 2 PLACEHOLDER**" but I had to explicitly change the drop down to "**-- Select --**" to make the content disappear.